# Monitoring progress in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I realise this is a very basic question: is there a way to monitor progress of generic functions in R / RStudio?

I have to deal with very large datasets and each transformation or calculation is taking a couple of minutes. I would like to check progress of generic or pre-programmed functions, e.g., `sum(vector)`. Has anything been foreseen in R or RStudio?

Rem: I am not looking at implementing progress bars in my own loops

Comment: If you're not looking to implement progress bars, then what kind of monitoring do you want?